# non unique combination of two unique columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table with columns **code, id** and **date** and some other date.
These columns are primary key together.

```
primary key(id, code, date)
```

I want them to be unique together. But a code cannot be duplicated in table with two different ids.
For example this is a possible situation:

```
id   code  date        data
1    123   3/28/2018   "data 1"
1    123   4/28/2018   "data 2"
```

or even this

```
1    123   3/28/2018   "data 1"
1    124   3/28/2018   "data 2"
```

while this is not:

```
id   code  date        data
1    123   3/28/2018   "data 1"
2    123   4/28/2018   "data 2"
```

it's possible to have two rows with code "123" only if id of both rows is 1. "123" cannot be combined with any other ids.

How can I manage this in sql server (version 14)?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide clear examples of what is and is not allowed.

Comment: Is the opposite possible? Having two different `code` values for the same `id`?

Comment: Yes it's possible. @SunKnight0

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong data model.

You need one table with only `id` and `code` (and whatever columns other than `date` might be relevant.  Let's call this table `codes` and the id, `code_id`, because that is how I would name them:

```
create table codes (
    code_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    code varchar(255) not null unique
);
```

There.  Now the mapping between `code_id` and `code` is one-to-one.  Next, create a table using only `code_id` and `date`:

```
create table code_dates (
    code_date_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    code_id int,
    date date,
    contraint fk_code_dates_code_id foreign key (code_id) references codes(code_id)
);
```

You can look up the `code` using `code_id`.  Voila!  Your data model is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there any way to do that without changing data model?

Comment: @madreza How do you expect fix this if you cannot change the data model?

Comment: I may change model, but I wanted to know if there is a way to do that. And I think what Tab Alleman suggests would work. @paparazzo

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is the best advice, but treating your question as academic, you can manage what you want using a CHECK CONSTRAINT in addition to the PRIMARY KEY you already have.

The CHECK CONSTRAINT would call a function that takes `id` and `code` as parameters.  The function queries the table and returns `true` if there is no other `id` that has that `code`, or `false` otherwise.   The CONSTRAINT allows only rows where the function returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This might do it

```
create table tmp (id int not null,  code int not null, dt datetime not null,  data varchar(10)
                   primary key (id, code, dt));
create function dbo.CheckFunction(@id int, @code int)
returns int
as begin
    return (select count(*) from tmp t where t.id <> @id and t.code = @code) 
end;
alter table tmp
add constraint chk_CheckFunction
check (dbo.CheckFunction(id, code) = 0);

truncate table tmp;
insert into tmp values 
       (1 ,123, '3/28/2018', 'data 1')
     , (1 ,123, '4/28/2018', 'data 2')
     , (1 ,123, '5/28/2018', 'data 2');
select * from tmp;
select count(*) from tmp t where t.id <> 1 and t.code = 123;
insert into tmp values 
       (2 ,123, '3/28/2018', 'data 1');
select * from tmp;

drop table tmp;
drop function dbo.CheckFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a Lookup table whose primary key is `id`, `code`? By putting a `UNIQUE` constraint on `code`, you will ensure that `code = 123` will only every pair up with `id = 1`. We cannot put `code = 123` against `id = 2` without violating the constraint.

Then put a referential constraint between the Lookup table and your Business table. Then, the referential constraint will bring over the constraints from the Lookup table into the Business table which will persist that `code = 123` can only every match with `id = 1`.

Something like:

```
DROP TABLE Business;
DROP TABLE Lookup;

CREATE TABLE Lookup
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    code INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Lookup Primary Key (id, code)
);

INSERT INTO Lookup VALUES (1, 123);
INSERT INTO Lookup VALUES (1, 124);
INSERT INTO Lookup VALUES (2, 123); -- Rejected

CREATE TABLE Business
(
  id int NOT NULL,
  code int NOT NULL,
  date date NOT NULL,
  data NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Business PRIMARY KEY (id, code, date),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Lookup FOREIGN KEY (id, code) REFERENCES Lookup (id, code)
);

INSERT INTO Business VALUES (1, 123, '2018-03-28', 'data 1');
INSERT INTO Business VALUES (1, 123, '2018-04-28', 'data 2');
INSERT INTO Business VALUES (1, 124, '2018-03-28', 'data 2');
INSERT INTO Business VALUES (2, 123, '2018-04-28', 'data 2'); -- Rejected
```